# My vba code is not seeing another sheet for no reason

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pretty long macro and it is working fine at my work computer. The problem is that it is not working on my home computer. The macros are stored in personal xlsm file at roaming. So I just copy paste the personal file to my computer and run the macro. Everything is perfect until it needs to take a data from sheet2 to sheet1, in same excel workbook. It gives runtime 1004 object defined error. Any thoughts?

```
Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov1 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[12]),IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov2 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov11 & "]),IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov3 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov22 & "]),-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov33 & "]))))"
    Range("R2").Select
```

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: Change `Thisworkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` or even better, define and set a workbook-type variable and use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: it doesn't have a thisworkbook or activeworkbook code. It activates before that. I can't paste all the code since it is too long but i can send one of the problematic parts.

Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov1 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[12]),IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov2 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov11 & "]),IF(RC[-2]<= " & MeanCov3 & ",-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov22 & "]),-AVERAGE(Sheet2!R[3]C[-13]:R[3]C[" & WeekCov33 & "]))))"
    Range("R2").Select

Comment: Simplest answer: Stop using Select and Activate. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: but how to switch between two open workbooks without select?

Answer (score -1):

Try using without select... Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = ...